# Avoid Typescript to compile some parts of code

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to avoid some code to be compiled with Typescript compiler dependent on a variable that must be entered on compiler commmand.
This will be usefull for make multiplatform apps that the code is very similar but with little differences. So instead of doing branches and merging all the time code you just tell compiler to not compile or compile some code.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Webpack for it? And also, by *some code*, you mean the entire of some JavaScript project, right (Not a partial build in  a specific project)?

Comment: Conditional compilation for Webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifdef-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [fdef-loader](https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader) which do it well. it doing preprocessing using WebPack and solve this issue for me.